# Android: Compensate for screen offset due to menus/toolbars?

Tags: android, graphics, view, coordinates, move

MotionEvent.getRawX/.getRawY return absolute coordinates (i.e. based on the entire screen). But the View receiving that MotionEvent may be (probably is) a child of yet another View, which itself may be at some offset on the screen, etc.

In particular, I'm experimenting with a basic app right now and the Android menu/tool bar (with the clock, etc.) is visible at the top of the screen. When I call .getRawX/.getRawY, I get accurate X/Y coordinates for the display as a whole - but how do I determine how those relate to the View's position on the screen if there can be menus, or if the (grand)parent view(s) are themselves smaller than the screen and offset from its edges?

Right now, if I use the return values from .getRawX/.getRawY to reposition the View, they work but the View "jumps" down by the height of the menu(s) at the top of the screen because the "absolute" Y value is essentially increased by the vertical offset of the parent View due to the menus above it. Thus there needs to be a general case approach for determining where the parent View(s) are in the absolute coordinates of the screen, so that the raw X/Y values can be adjusted before being used to reposition the View in question.

I'm not bothering to post code because it's basically a duplicate of every other example of "move a View by touch" on this and many other websites. I don't have a bug I'm trying to find... I'm looking for the way to relate MotionEvent's absolute coordinates with the relative coordinates of any app that isn't running 100% full screen.

Answer (score 3):

You can use View.getLocationOnScreen() to find the view's absolute screen coordinates, and then work everything out in screen coordinates and/or do you own conversion based on that.

Comment: Awesome, that's exactly what I was looking for. There's so much depth to the classes that it's sometimes hard to find that needle in the haystack. However, see my edits above for more comments. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Based on GreyBeardedGeek's tip about .getLocationOnScreen, here is a sample onTouchListener that moves a View with a finger. It successfully accommodates menus, toolbars, status bars, the parent View not being centered on either axis, etc. I thought I'd share this since I've seen so many posts on the topic but none that really completely answered the question. It is intentionally wordy, and uses more locals than is necessary, to help illustrate what is happening.

```
public boolean  onTouch(View v,MotionEvent event) {

    boolean bExitValue = true;
    int             iOffsetX;
    int             iOffsetY;
    int             iNewX;
    int             iNewY;
    int[]           aLocation = new int [ 2 ];
    int             iAction;

    iAction = event.getActionMasked();

    if (MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE == iAction) {
        v.getLocationOnScreen(aLocation);                   // get absolute physical location of this View
        iOffsetX =  (aLocation [ 0 ] - (int) v.getX());     // subtract out this View's relative location within its parent View...
        iOffsetY =  (aLocation [ 1 ] - (int) v.getY());     // ...yielding the offsets that convert getRawX/Y's coords to setX/Y's coords

        iNewX = (int) event.getRawX();                      // get absolute physical coords of this touch
        iNewY = (int) event.getRawY();
        iNewX -= iOffsetX;                                  // remove parent View's screen offset (calc'd above)
        iNewY -= iOffsetY;
        iNewX -= iRelX;                                     // remove stored touch offset
        iNewY -= iRelY;
        v.setX(iNewX);                                      // finally, move View to new coords (relative to its parent View)
        v.setY(iNewY);
    }

    else if (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN == iAction) {
        iRelX = (int) event.getX();                         // preserve offset of this touch within the View
        iRelY = (int) event.getY();
    }

    else {
        bExitValue = false;
    }

    return(bExitValue);

}
```

Key points:

- The touch's offset within the View must be captured and stored in your ACTION_DOWN handler to Class-level fields (i.e. static variables). You want to preserve this offset so the View maintains its positional relationship with the finger, but you can't just grab a fresh copy with every ACTION_MOVE because they will exactly offset the finger movement and no movement will occur.
- View.getLocationOnScreen returns absolute coordinates, whereas View.getX/Y returns coordinates relative to the parent View. This is how non-fullscreen parent Views are handled. The difference between these two coordinate pairs is the offset that converts MotionEvent.getRawX/Y's absolute coordinates to the parent-View-relative coordinates required by View.setX/Y.

A big thanks to GreyBeardedGeek for identifying View.getLocationOnScreen. Hopefully this code excerpt will help someone else. Thanks!